# Can I apply centripetal force

Tags: centripetal-force

Suppose you have some object moving near a large planet. We can use energy conservation to obtain $K+U$ is constant. Also $F_c=F_g$, (I believe we can apply this even though we are not moving in a circle nessecarily) which relates $v$ to the distance of the object $d$ to the center of the planet. But $K+U$ also relates $d$ and $v$ so we have two equations,two unknowns so $v,d$ are determined. This is an obvious contradiction. So I guess you cannot apply centripetal force the way I did. But why? Radial acceleration is always $v^2/r$, I thought, even if you are not moving in a circle.

Comment: $v^2/r$ is equal to centripetal acceleration only for circular motion.  Given the constraints of a circle, a given $K+U$ will result in a single $v,d$.

Comment: Not according to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_force

Comment: The $v$ in the wikipedia equations is the tangential speed, not the total speed.  Yes, if you change $v$ to $v_{tangential}$, the equation is correct.  But you have to know the angle to do that.

Comment: Ahhhh okay I am stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate the conservation of energy equation with respect to time $dE\over dt$so that it equals zero and see where that leads you.

Comment: Ok I'l do it out. From $F_c=F_g$, $v^2/d=GM/d^2$ so $v^2=GM/d$. From energy conservation, $.5mv^2-GmM/d$ is constant, so $.5v^2-GM/d$ is constant. Substitute the $v$ we found above, you get $.5(GM/d^2)-GM/d$ is constant. So $d$ has only two possible values (one possibly extraneous). This is the contradiction.

Comment: @JefPauwels this in not an answer, but a comment. If you have a remark or a question to the author of the question, you have to put it in a comment.

Comment: JefPauwels I thought about that. But before doing that I would like to clear this up.

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou : I think that you have to check whether you are not doing a mistake about the direction of the centripetal force. The gravitation force is along the vector connecting the object with the center of the planet. But $F_c$ is normal to the tangential velocity. I am not sure whether $F_c$ and $F_g$ are along the same direction.